# Pixel format bit endianness

Tags: image, video, ffmpeg, pixel, bmp

I am currently implementing a program to read and decode image from a BMP file. But I am really confused about the pixel format and especially about bit endianness.

My current understanding is when referring to a pixel format, e.g. **RGBA32**, we are saying it in our human way, which is using big endian, thus the first byte is R, second G, third B, fourth A:

```
RGBA32
11111111 22222222 33333333 44444444
R        G        B        A
```

And when appending big/little endian to this format, such as **RGBA32BE**/**RGBA32LE**, this will change the byte order accordingly, as:

```
RGBA32BE (unchanged)
11111111 22222222 33333333 44444444
R        G        B        A

RGBA32LE (reversed)
11111111 22222222 33333333 44444444
A        B        G        R
```

This all looks naturally to me, as long as we are assuming the individual value of each component is exactly the value of byte we read.

However things start to confuse me when component size is less than 1 byte or 8 bits. Say [**RGB555BE**](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/0.11/pixfmt_8h.html#:%7E:text=packed%20RGB%205%3A5%3A5%2C%2016bpp%2C%20(msb)1A%205R%205G%205B(lsb)%2C%20big%2Dendian%2C%20most%20significant%20bit%20to%200), I suppose below is how it is represented as byte array:

```
RGB555BE
1'22222'33 333'44444
A   R      G     B
0'00001'00 000'00000
```

1. Do we read the R component as `10000=16` or `00001=1` ?
2. I'm even more confused about if the way we read the component (bit endianness) is related to byte endianness?
3. Which way is **RGB555LE** format represented in byte array?

   ```
   RGB555LE_v1
   333'44444 1'22222'33
   G"    B   A   R   G'
   000'00000 0'00001'00

   or RGB555LE_v2 ?
   44444'333 33'22222'1
     B     G      R   A
   00000'000 00'10000'0
   ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may use FFmpeg for testing the different pixel formats.

The conclusion are:

- There is no bit endianness, only bytes endianness.
- The endianness is relevant when the base elements is 2 bytes (`uint16`).
  Little endian: bytes order of `uint16` element is: [LSB, MSB].
  Bit endian: bytes order of `uint16` element is: [MSB, LSB].

---

Executing FFmpeg CLI commands for testing:

Start with `rgb24` for example:

```
ffmpeg -y -lavfi color=red:size=8x8:rate=1:duration=1 -pix_fmt rgb24 -f rawvideo red.raw
ffmpeg -y -lavfi color=0x00FF00:size=8x8:rate=1:duration=1 -pix_fmt rgb24 -f rawvideo green.raw
ffmpeg -y -lavfi color=blue:size=8x8:rate=1:duration=1 -pix_fmt rgb24 -f rawvideo blue.raw
```

Use some hex viewer like [HxD](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) for inspecting the raw file content.

`red.raw     FF 00 00 FF 00 00`...
`blue.raw    00 FF 00 00 FF 00`...
`green.raw   00 00 FF 00 00 FF`...

---

`rgba` pixel format:

```
ffmpeg -y -lavfi color=red:size=8x8:rate=1:duration=1 -pix_fmt rgba -f rawvideo red.raw
ffmpeg -y -lavfi color=0x00FF00:size=8x8:rate=1:duration=1 -pix_fmt rgba -f rawvideo green.raw
ffmpeg -y -lavfi color=blue:size=8x8:rate=1:duration=1 -pix_fmt rgba -f rawvideo blue.raw
```

r: `FF 00 00 FF`
g: `00 FF 00 FF`
b: `00 00 FF FF`

The FFmpeg convention the order of the bytes.
We can't say if the naming applies little or big endian.
The endianness is relevant when using `uint16` components (not `uint8` components).

---

`rgba` pixel format:

```
ffmpeg -y -lavfi color=red:size=8x8:rate=1:duration=1 -pix_fmt rgba -f rawvideo red.raw
ffmpeg -y -lavfi color=0x00FF00:size=8x8:rate=1:duration=1 -pix_fmt rgba -f rawvideo green.raw
ffmpeg -y -lavfi color=blue:size=8x8:rate=1:duration=1 -pix_fmt rgba -f rawvideo blue.raw
```

r: `FF 00 00 FF`
g: `00 FF 00 FF`
b: `00 00 FF FF`

`A` then `R` then `G` then `B` then `A`...

We may refer `rgba` as `RGBA32BE`, but it's too confusing...

---

`rgb555le` pixel format:

```
ffmpeg -y -lavfi color=red:size=8x8:rate=1:duration=1 -pix_fmt rgb555le -f rawvideo red.raw
ffmpeg -y -lavfi color=0x00FF00:size=8x8:rate=1:duration=1 -pix_fmt rgb555le -f rawvideo green.raw
ffmpeg -y -lavfi color=blue:size=8x8:rate=1:duration=1 -pix_fmt rgb555le -f rawvideo blue.raw
```

r: `00 7C 00 7C`
g: `E0 03 E0 03`
b: `1F 00 1F 00`

We may also check the lower bit (for bits ordering):
Set the color to 8 so after shifting the value be 1.

```
ffmpeg -y -lavfi color=0x000008:size=8x8:rate=1:duration=1 -pix_fmt rgb555le -f rawvideo red.raw
ffmpeg -y -lavfi color=0x000800:size=8x8:rate=1:duration=1 -pix_fmt rgb555le -f rawvideo green.raw
ffmpeg -y -lavfi color=0x080000:size=8x8:rate=1:duration=1 -pix_fmt rgb555le -f rawvideo blue.raw
```

r: `01 00 01 00` 2 bytes in bits: `00000001 00000000`
g: `20 00 20 00` 2 bytes in bits: `00100000 00000000`
b: `00 04 00 04` 2 bytes in bits: `00000000 00000100`

---

rgb555be pixel format:

```
ffmpeg -y -lavfi color=red:size=8x8:rate=1:duration=1 -pix_fmt rgb555be -f rawvideo red.raw
ffmpeg -y -lavfi color=0x00FF00:size=8x8:rate=1:duration=1 -pix_fmt rgb555be -f rawvideo green.raw
ffmpeg -y -lavfi color=blue:size=8x8:rate=1:duration=1 -pix_fmt rgb555be -f rawvideo blue.raw
```

r: `7C 00 7C 00`
g: `03 E0 03 E0`
b: `00 1F 00 1F`

Checking the lower bit (for bits ordering):

```
ffmpeg -y -lavfi color=0x000008:size=8x8:rate=1:duration=1 -pix_fmt rgb555be -f rawvideo red.raw
ffmpeg -y -lavfi color=0x000800:size=8x8:rate=1:duration=1 -pix_fmt rgb555be -f rawvideo green.raw
ffmpeg -y -lavfi color=0x080000:size=8x8:rate=1:duration=1 -pix_fmt rgb555be -f rawvideo blue.raw
```

r: `00 01 00 01`
g: `00 20 00 20`
b: `04 00 04 00`

In big endian format, only the bytes are swapped.
(For every uint16 element (two bytes), order of the first and second byte is swapped).

---

**Answers to questions:**

1. Do we read the R component as `10000=16` or `00001=1 ?`

Answer:
For rgb555le: `00000001 00000000`
For rgb555be: `00000000 00000001`

---

2. I'm even more confused about if the way we read the component (bit endianness) is related to byte endianness?

Answer:
In context of pixel format, there is no "bit endianness" there is only "byte endianness".

Bits endianness is more relevant to serial communication, from software perspective, we don't see the order of bits in each byte.

---

3. Which way is RGB555LE format represented in byte array?

Answer:

RGB555LE (as RGB555LE_v1):

`byte0    byte1`
`gggbbbbb 0rrrrrgg`

(most left bit is the upper bit in each byte).

We better look at the data as one `uint16` element:

b: `0000000000011111` (pure blue)
g: `0000001111100000` (pure green)
r: `0111110000000000` (pure red)

We may look at it as `uint16` as: `0rrrrrgggggbbbbb`

Comment: Thank you so much for your comprehensive and detailed answer! I was reading ffmpeg source today and have just finally figured out that there is really no bit endianness (or we might say always big bit endian, because we read the multibyte, in big or little byte endian, and shift bits to get component.

Comment: However I still have some problems about bit ordering. In pixel format, it seems the bits in each byte is labeled as 7 6 ... 1 0 from most significant bit to least significant bit. However to read other data that are not inherently combined to bytes, e.g. in the BMP format when using palette, the pixel array is index to the palette table, if each pixel use a 2 bit index, how are the four index in one byte arranged? Is it 00 11 22 33 or 33 22 11 00?

Comment: I think the confusion comes from the way it is written. In English we start writing from left to right, but for numbers the LSD (least significand digit) is the most right digit. Read it as a number `33221100`. `00` is the lowest two bits, and it is the first index.

Comment: Understand, I will try some more experiments to verify it. Again, thank you, sincerely.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think endianness matters to `rgb555`, and that's why your link bunches `rgb555`, `rgb555le`, and `rgb555be` together. For that matter, your example with `rgba` also isn't endian sensitive as its components are all <= 8 bits.

As for how `rgb555` is represented in 2 bytes (well, 15 bits), you can search FFmpeg repo for `rgb555` and see how encoders/decoders handle such pixel format. Here is one I found [`rpzaenc.c` Line 138](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/7af1a3cebef6d9654675252f57689d46ac17d1e9/libavcodec/rpzaenc.c#L138):

```c
static uint16_t rgb24_to_rgb555(uint8_t *rgb24)
{
    uint16_t rgb555 = 0;
    uint32_t r, g, b;

    r = rgb24[0] >> 3;
    g = rgb24[1] >> 3;
    b = rgb24[2] >> 3;

    rgb555 |= (r << 10);
    rgb555 |= (g << 5);
    rgb555 |= (b << 0);

    return rgb555;
}
```

the encoder takes `rgb555`, a 16-bit unsigned int, an uses `put_bits()`  utility function to push these 15 bits to its bitstream as shown on [Line 683](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/7af1a3cebef6d9654675252f57689d46ac17d1e9/libavcodec/rpzaenc.c#L683)

```c
put_bits(&s->pb, 16, rgb24_to_rgb555(avg_color));
```

Here is the link to [put_bits.h](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/636631d9db82f5e86330ab42dacc8a106684b349/libavcodec/put_bits.h)

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. I'll have a look about it.